# Initialize array with "static" changes run time?

Tags: c, arrays, gcc

I noticed that two different ways of initializing an array in C seems to result in very different running time after compiling with O3 optimization. Here is a minimum (albeit meaningless) example to replicate such difference:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    int i, j, k;
    int size=10000;
    int a[size];
    clock_t time1 = clock();
    for (i=0; i<size; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<300000; j++) {
            for (k=0; k<700000; k++) {
                a[i] = j+k;
            }
        }
    }
    clock_t time2 = clock();
    double time = (double)(time2-time1)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC*1000.0;
    printf("%f\n", time);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Compile this program with *gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609* with O3 optimization turned on. This program takes about **0.02s** to finish on my computer.

Now, change the array initialization from "int a[size];" to "static int a[10000];" and keep everything else the same. Again compile with the same environment and O3 optimization. This time, the program runs for about **0.001s**.

Can anyone explain why there is such a different? Thanks!

Comment: You changed to static and used a constant rather than the VLA code you've shown.  You changed 2 things so who knows which one might make a difference?

Comment: Compile with `-S` and look at the assembly.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thanks for pointing this out. If I use "static int a[size];" (i.e., use the variable name instead of constant 10000), then I get error "storage size of ‘a’ isn’t constant". That's why I did "static int a[10000];"

Comment: @user3386109 Could you please say a little about what to look for? Thanks!

Comment: `static` is not an initialiser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this largely depends on compiler. My GCC 5.4 completely removes the loop when static is present, probly because it can figure out that computations have no side-effects ("dead code elimination"). For some reason it fails to do so when VLA is present (that's a missing optimization).

As a side note, to reliably measure performance you need to prevent compiler from optimizing too much. In your case I'd suggest to separate array creation and computations e.g. like

```
void __attribute__((noinline, noclone)) benchmark(int *a, int size) {
  for (i=0; i<size; i++)
  for (j=0; j<300000; j++)
  for (k=0; k<700000; k++)
    a[i] = j+k;
}

int main(void) {
  int i, j, k;
  int size=10000;
  int a[size];
  clock_t time1 = clock();
  benchmark(a, size);
  clock_t time2 = clock();
  double time = (double)(time2-time1)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC*1000.0;
  printf("%f\n", time);
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful!